# Increase brightness of HDR to light the scene, but keeping the background at a lower exposure

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, light, lighting

I have a scene in which I am using an HDRI texture as a light source.  However, I am also trying to use it as a background, but when I turn up the strength of the sky it just turns white.  I am looking for a way to render the sky again(at a lower exposure) and then composite the sky under the rendered object.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image

Comment: If I layout the HDRI onto a sphere I can use https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig to determine if the camera ray is hitting it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can simply use the light path node directly in your world shader tree

Comment: That works too, now I don't have to have a giant sphere in my scene.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69605/how-can-i-create-a-silhouette-using-hdr-in-cycles/69615#69615

Comment: Also read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im/46940#46940

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use two nodes for the background, one to light the scene at the intensity you want and one with the normal exposure that is only seen by the camera:
Control the mix using a light path using Is Camera Ray.

[image]