# How to make a window brighter without changing light of other objects in the room?

Tags: light, hdri

How to make window area brighter (almost white) without changing the light of other objects inside the room? My work:

[image]

I'm using HDRI

Comment: Hi. Please use the [built-in image upload](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1081/23985) to imgur if you want to add images to your question. Images on other services tend to "vanish" over time, rendering your question and possible answers useless to people who search for answers to the same question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase brightness of HDR to light the scene, but keeping the background at a lower exposure](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113908/increase-brightness-of-hdr-to-light-the-scene-but-keeping-the-background-at-a-l)

Comment: Please add an image of the material node tree you are using for the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the brightness of the HDR with the slider for the World>Surface>Strength.

See:

[How can I create a silhouette using HDR in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69605/how-can-i-create-a-silhouette-using-hdr-in-cycles/69615#69615)

To use two different light intensities in the same image used for the background, one to light the scene and one that is only seen by the camera you can use a light path and use "is camera ray" to control the mix of two different background nodes

Read:  [Increase brightness of HDR to light the scene, but keeping the background at a lower exposure](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113908/increase-brightness-of-hdr-to-light-the-scene-but-keeping-the-background-at-a-l/113945#113945)