# How to get a correct natural illuminance while preserving the physics correctness of the lights

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I read Cycles sun is physically correct (radiant flux at sea-level is 1050 W/m² according to [this source](https://blendergrid.com/news/cycles-physically-correct-brightness)).

With a clear sky luminous efficacy of 100 lm/W, this should, with the support of a World surface texture, lead to the expected 110-120 klx global illuminance.

However on the images the indoor scene is very dark, and the rendering noisy (in spite of using two [light portals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/what-does-light-portal-mean)):

[image]

[image]

The scene is using Blender units, openings are 2 units high. Switching to SI units doesn't improve. In addition a large portion of the color values is nearly unused (5 pixels only in the upper quarter of the histogram):

[image]

**Question 1**: What can explain this relatively low brightness indoor, compared to a real room.

[image]
<sup>Source: [www.apartmentsapart.com](http://www.apartmentsapart.com/europe/netherlands/zandvoort/apartments/detail/137803)</sup>

Did I miss something in the use of the sun and environment lighting?

**Question 2**: Previously I solved this by adding lights, outdoor or indoor, but this leaves a visible effect on the walls (brightness that can't come from the sun; natural shadows weakened or lost, etc). Is it possible to prevent this from happening. How is this dealt with usually?

---

Additional questions, in case someone wants to shed more light on the topic:

- Is there a mean to measure the final illuminance of a given area?
- How does Blender compensate for different dynamic ranges. Does it adjust the sensitivity of its renderer (like adjusting the pupil of an eye, or changing the ISO number of a sensor)? Is there a way to influence this setting? Should it be used?

---

[image]

Comment: "*Does it adjust the sensitivity of its renderer (like adjusting the pupil of an eye, or changing the ISO number of a sensor)*" No, but you can manually [control exposure](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/exact-meaning-of-film-exposure-in-blender-cycles) or [Color Manage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im) your scene